# Emacs java indentation off by one space

Tags: java, emacs, indentation

As far as I know, the only related thing I have in my .emacs is the following:

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

When I indent java files, it looks fine in emacs. However, in git, it shows up like this:

```
    int a = 0;  // regular line with 4 spaces
   int b = 0;  // emacs indent: 1 space less
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Try `M-x whitespace-mode` to double-check that Emacs doesn't actually insert any tabs.

Comment: Thanks @legoscia, it was inserting tabs. Strangely, I had `setq indent-tabs-mode nil`, but changing it to `setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil` fixed it.

Comment: Please write your findings up as an answer which you then accept as the solution (for future reference).

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about that - `indent-tabs-mode` is a special variable that automatically becomes buffer-local when set. That's why `setq` in `.emacs` doesn't do what you want.